# Router cakephp pointing to same action

Tags: php, cakephp

I am facing some problems in routing under cakephp
there are two actions in my controller
they are as below:

```
example.com/posts/show/show-by-day
example.com/posts/view/slug-post
```

I want them as:

```
example.com/article/show-by-day.html
example.com/article/slug-post.html
```

So i routes file under config file I wrote as:

```
Router::connect('/article/:show_by_day', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'show'), array('pass' => array('show_by_day'))); 

Router::connect('/article/:slug', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('slug')));
```

its working fine when I hit the url example.com/article/show-by-day.html

but when I hit url example.com/article/slug-post.html , its again point to action show.

So how can I solve it?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Router::connect( '/article/show-by-day.html', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'show'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('show_by_day')
    )
);

Router::connect( '/article/slug-post.html', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'view'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('slug')
    )
);
```

Explanation:
The first parameter of the `Router::connect` is the exact URL you want to match - in the original code, a `:` was included - which parameterized the URL instead of using exact match. The second and third paramters in `Router::connect` are the actual controller / action that need to be invoked along with required parameters.

Comment: Can you explain a little? I don't think your answer follows his desired URL structure